# Find least colorful path in a graph

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, breadth-first-search, np-complete

The problem i'm trying to solve is this:

Given a graph G = (V,E) such that every **edge** is colored in one of 10 colors, and two vertices: s, t.

I need to find an algorithm that produces a (shortest) path from s to t, that goes over a minimal amount of colors.

My idea was to duplicate the graph 10 times:

The first duplicate will include only edges of one color

The second will include only edges of two colors... and so on.

Also, I connect an outer node: s' to every "s" node in every duplicate.

But, it has occurred to me that for this approach I need to duplicate the graph not 10 times but around 10! (or maybe even 2^10?) times for every combination of  colors.

So what would be an efficient algorithm to solve this?

Comment: What is more important, shortest or minimal amount of colors? Are trade offs possible (e.g. one more color makes up for 2 edges, ...).

Comment: Minimal amount of colors is more important. I rather make the path longer than to add another color to it.

Comment: Can you share the problem source

Comment: Why is it relevant?

Comment: If the quality of the solution is measured by theoretical Big-O metrics, note that 10! and 2^10 are both constants.

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer what are the constraints on number of edges and no. of vertices on the graph ?

Comment: @Jim D. , I know. But it's a really big constant... Also it feels that there is a better approach.

Comment: @Amit Kumar, there aren't any additional constraints.

Comment: The problem is NP hard, so if you find an efficient algorithm you'll be $1M richer and famous :) See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe there's an easy algorithm to solve this, since the general form of the problem is NP hard. That is, in an arbitrarily colored graph, finding a shortest path between two vertices which touches a minimal set of colors is NP hard.

Thus, while it's possible there's slightly better algorithms, your idea of solving 1024 variants of the graph (one for each subset of of your 10 colors) is likely to be reasonable.

## Proof

The proof works by reducing the hitting set problem to it. The hitting set problem is NP complete, so the reduction to your problem shows your problem is NP hard.

Recall that the hitting set problem takes sets X1...Xn, each with elements from some universe U and one is asked to find a minimal set {x1, ..., xk} such that for all i, there's a j such that xj in Xi.

The colors in the graph will be elements of U. Let the graph itself consist of n+1 vertices. These will be X0 (a start node, named only for notational convenience below) and vertices representing X1 ... Xn.

For each x in Xi+1, connect Xi to Xi+1 with an edge of color x.

Then in this graph, all paths from X0 to Xn have length n, but one that uses a minimal number of colors corresponds exactly a minimum hitting set.

Note that this expands the definition of graph to include multiple edges between nodes. If that's not ok then one add an extra node in the middle of each edge of the constructed graph.

Comment: Thank you for the educating answer! That said, can you think of an algorithm that will work (in the best complexity possible) ?

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer the best complexity possible is not known (since that would prove or disprove P=NP). So no :)

Comment: What about ANY algorithm? Say With 1024 graph duplications?

Comment: what about a path that is not simple?

Comment: A non-simple path contains loops. Those loops can be removed (which doesn't increase the number of colors, and decreases the length of the path), leaving a simple path. Or to put it another way, a non-simple path may contain the minimal number of colors, but it is never also the shortest path using those colors.

Comment: I don't understand the question about ANY algorithm. You suggest in your question using any shortest path algorithm on 1024 copies of the graph (one for each subset of colors), and I mention that in my answer. If you are asking for an algorithm that finds shortest paths then Dijkstra's is one.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
As suggested by Paul , the below approach won't work.

Try this approach, i am not sure about the correctness.

Start by merging nodes , which are same of same color and share a edge. This will shrink the graph which will then only contain edges (u->v) where u and v both have different colors .

After this give a constant weight to all the edges in the graph.
Run dijkstra over the graph and keep track of the colors you have visited, and everytime you visit a new color , update the whole unvisited graph with new higher weights from visited to non-visted nodes which are not in the set of used colors.

Comment: Agree with @Paul that this will not work.  If you want to use some generalization of Dijkstra's algorithm, you will need to keep track of shortest paths to nodes using different subsets of colors.