# Find best path by arbitrary weight function?

Tags: algorithm, graph

How can I find the best path by an arbitrary weight function? That means a function that says how "good" a path is, for example number of edge colors. The function will never score a path "better" than all of its subpaths.

I used the Dijkstra-Algorithm but with the score function instead of the length determining which path will be expanded next, but Im not sure if it is the best solution or if there are cases where the best path will never be found.

Answer (score 1):

The particular problem you're describing - finding a path between two nodes that minimizes the number of colors used - is **NP**-hard. This means that, assuming **P** ≠ **NP**, there is no polynomial-time algorithm for solving this problem, and in particular Dijkstra's algorithm won't work here.

Here's a reduction that shows this, which is based on [this excellent answer by Paul Hankin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41923938/501557) for a related problem. We're going to reduce the *hitting set problem* to the problem of finding the least-colorful s-t path in a graph. In the hitting set problem, you're given a collection of sets S<sub>1</sub>, ..., S<sub>n</sub> containing a total of m elements and a number k, then asked whether it's possible to pick k elements such that each set S<sub>i</sub> contains at least one of them.

The reduction works as follows. We're going to build a graph and color the nodes one of m+1 colors. The first color (we'll call it black) is a neutral color with no meaning. The remaining m colors will then correspond to the different elements from the sets.

We'll construct a chain of "gadgets," one per set S<sub>i</sub>, which correspond to choosing some element from S<sub>i</sub>. Here's how each gadget works:

- Each gadget has a start node s<sub>i</sub>, colored black, and an end node f<sub>i</sub>, also colored black.
- For each element x ∈ S<sub>i</sub>, we add a new node x<sub>i</sub> given the color associated with element x. We then add an edge from s<sub>i</sub> to x<sub>i</sub> and from x<sub>i</sub> and t<sub>i</sub>.

Now, imagine walking from s<sub>i</sub> to t<sub>i</sub>. You have to take two steps to do this, visiting two black nodes (s<sub>i</sub> and t<sub>i</sub>) and one node of a different color. Walking through that colored node corresponds to selecting x<sub>i</sub> as one of the elements of your hitting set.

To finish things up, wire up all the gadgets in series by linking f<sub>1</sub> to s<sub>2</sub>, f<sub>2</sub> to s<sub>3</sub>, etc. Now, look at any path from s<sub>1</sub> to f<sub>n</sub>. If you can find a path through the graph that uses at most k+1 colors, one of those colors will be black, and the other k colors correspond to a collection of k elements that collectively contain one element out of each of the sets S<sub>i</sub>. You've found your hitting set - great! On the flipside, imagine you have a hitting set of size k. Then walk from s<sub>1</sub> to f<sub>n</sub>, making the choice at each point at which you have to pick a colored node corresponding to one of the items from the hitting set. Then you'll use at most k+1 colors: black plus the hitting set colors.

This graph contains 2n nodes for the s<sub>i</sub> and t<sub>i</sub> nodes, plus one node for each element of each set, with a linear number of edges. It's therefore polynomially-sized with respect to the instance of hitting set, so this is a polynomial-time reduction from hitting set to your problem.

Sorry for the (probably) negative result!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not able to fully understand this proof, but I get that the color problem is hard to solve. In the case of the color problem, the path weight is not equal to or greater than the weight of the subpaths. (For example if we split the best path with 2 colors in half these two could both have a weight of 2, but the whole path has not weight >=4) Would dijkstras algorithm be able to find the best path if this would be the case?